# remove an field from mongodb using mongoose

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

this is my `model function`,

```
Project.collection.findOneAndUpdate(query, updatedProject)
  .then((res) => {
      if (res) {
        return resolve(res);
      } else reject();
   })
  .catch((err) => {
    return reject(err);
   });
```

updatedProject holds json data like,

```
{
"data":"has data",
"fields":"some data"
}
```

and `query` holds,

```
let query = { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(projectId)}
```

now my `database` document `project collection` data is,

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("5b446a58ab89ec3cc34c2bec"),
"name":"my name",
"data":"has data123",
"fields":"some data123",
"record":{
      "data1":"some records",
      "data2":"some records",
      "data3":"some records"
}
}
```

Now, my updatedProject holds `only data,fields`, so im expecting other fields name, `record to be removed`, but it `responds` back `with all the fields` with updated value,

but if i pass updateProject like this,

```
"record":{
          "data1":"some new records"
         }
```

it just `works` as expected (removes `data2` and `data3`),

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: here you are replacing your `record` object with new object that's why other fields are being removed but to remove fields from the root document you need to use `$unset` operator...

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet is there any ways, other than using $unset ?

Comment: Nopes... You have to use `$unset` in order to remove the fields from the root document